# How do I avoid giving username and password to git push/pull/fetch on my local machine?

Tags: git, ssh

Whenever I have to do push/pull/fetch a version controlled code (via Git) I always have to provide users/pass details.

I tried to setup an ssh-key but I am not familiar with that.

Is there a step-by-step guide to get started using another way to verify oneself?

Comment: Are you pushing/pulling/.. via command line..?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner Yes. Always via command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're pushing/pulling via command line.
When you're requested to type in your username/password each and every time, that usually means you cloned the repository via `git clone https://github.com/username/repo-name` initially.

You can overcome that by cloning it via ssh like so:

```
git clone git@github.com:username/repo-name
```

Before that you should've registered your ssh-key to Github. You can read more on that topic [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).

You can change how the repo is being pulled/push inside the configuration that comes with the cloned repo.
Navigate into your local repository and open `.git/config` with your favorite editor.
Then change the following block that looks similar to the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/username/repo-name
```

to

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:username/repo-name
```

Afterwards, save the file and you're done.

Comment: Can I modify the config via `git remote rm origin` and `git remote add origin url`

Comment: Yes, as far as I know `git remote add/rm` does achieve the same result :)
I like doing it manually though. This way I know for sure what's set up. You can check your remotes via `git remote -v`.